# Numbers insert into database but not characters or numbers/characters

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, ajax

So I have an input on a page and I am passing the value of the input into an ajax POST request. I've logged everything in my javascript file and all is as expected.

In my php file I set it to $message = $_POST["message"]; and is gete inserted into my table like this message, with VALUES set to $message.

In my success callback $result = mysql_query($sql); I am passing an array with the $message. I then log it in my ajax success callback and it logs correctly when I send numbers but $result fails when I send and characters or combo of characters and numbers.

It sounds like the column is set to INT but it is not. I have tried VCHAR, TEXT, LONGTEXT. I even deleted the column and made a new one. Here is how I have it varchar(120) utf8_bin No None.
I even tried to cast as a string in php.

Any ideas? I like the detective work involved in trying to figure it out myself but I am stumped.

Thanks for helping.

Further info:
This is how I am sanitizing $message.

$message = $_POST["message"];

$message = strip_tags($message);

$message = htmlspecialchars(mysql_real_escape_string($message));

Comment: On a side note, you should refrain from using `mysql_*` in NEW code, it's officially deprecated as of PHP 5.5.0. Instead, you should be using [mysqli_*](http://codular.com/php-mysqli) or [PDO](http://uk1.php.net/PDO). See a comparison of said APIs [here](http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqlinfo.api.choosing.php).

Answer (score 0):

Well that's wrong.

```
mysql_query("insert into `tablename` (`message`) values "
            ."('".mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['message'])."')");
```

All you need. `strip_tags` and `htmlspecialchars` are *not* appropriate for inserting into a database. Pay attention to the fact that a string needs quotes!

Comment: Cool, thanks for that. I'll get that fixed up. FYI, I am also inserting geo coordinates and google map api data into the table and that is working. It was when I added the message column I had the problem. Thanks!